# Is it possible to play Starcraft 2 at an Internet Cafe without a licence?

Tags: starcraft-2

I recently tried to check out Starcraft 2 at an internet cafe before deciding to buy it. However it would not let me play the game without a battle.net account. After registering for the account it would still not let me play because the account did not have the correct license attached.

What is the best way to play Starcraft2 before deciding to purchase the game? I did a brief search but could not find a demo version and if I cannot play at an internet cafe (which I assume would purchase legal copies under a site license) what other options are there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 'guest pass' brochures that come with a copy of Starcraft 2 for just this purpose!  Typically I believe they last around 7 in game hours or 14 real-time days, providing you a good opportunity to get addicted.  If you have friends that have the game, ask them to give you one of their invites, if not I'm sure you could find one for virtually no price online.

Here are some for a dollar on [ebay](http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=starcraft+2+guest+pass&_sacat=See-All-Categories)

If the Internet Cafe has Starcraft 2 already installed, you can also select 'play offline' from the login menu.  This will give you access to the single player game.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anyone who owns the game. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: updated with a link to ebay, there are guest passes on there for as cheap as a dollar

Comment: NB: Guest passes only came with the boxed version of the game, not the digital download.

Comment: @Akusete I should have an unused guest pass around if you're willing to disclose your email I can send it. Me and 2 of my roommates bought it, so we have a few unused still.

Comment: @en1gmatic325: Thanks for the offer, but I dont have a computer that can run SC2 at the moment.

Comment: Does this still hold true in 2017?

Answer (score 6):

Even though you can't play multiplayer, the copy of starcraft 2 at the internet cafe should still allow you to play the single player mode in "offline mode".

If you're just interested in determining whether or not you like the game, Single Player is probably a good metric for that (though it features several aspects that don't carry over into the multiplayer portion of the game).

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question, "Is it possible to play SC2 at an Internet Cafe without a licence?". At the login screen you can select to "Play Offline."

Comment: It was a few months ago so my memory is fuzzy, however I distinctly remember it not allowing me to play offline either. Perhaps that was a separate issue though.

Answer (score 2):

Did you speak with the people running the place?  I imagine they must have registered the CD-key to *some* account, with the intention of allowing their customers to use it..

Comment: Good Idea: The counter was pretty busy so I just started playing another game.

Comment: @Akusete: Well there's your problem, chief.  They're not going to give you the username/password to type in yourself; there'd be nothing stopping from, for instance, changing the password, or using the account at home.

Comment: Starcraft 2 does not have a CD-key. The key provided is to activate your account. You can install Starcraft 2 without any key.